# Incorrect width/height of image downloaded from get_serving_url() from Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

This is so weird.

On localhost when testing everything seems fine, an image which is 616x710 pixels uploaded to the localhost and fetched using get_serving_url() shows up in browser in the correct 616x710 pixels.

The exact same png with the exact same app deployed at Google App Engine currently shows up as 444x512 pixels. What is going on??? Known issue?

Comment: This comes up periodically. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868749/gae-appengine-appears-to-resize-my-image-upon-posting/11869787 for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Found how to fix it... it's weird but we have to add =s0 at the end of the serving url to be sure to get original dimensions back.... why oh why

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions